# Почему не работает метод __init__

Tags: python

```
class Dog:
    def __int__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sit(self):
        print(f"{self.name} is now sitting")

    def roll_over(self):
        print(f"{self.name} rolled over")

my_dog = Dog("Bob", 4)

print(f"\nMy dog name is {my_dog.name}")
print(f"\nMy dog is {my_dog.age} years old")
my_dog.sit()`
```

Comment: В заголовке, причём, правильно написал...

Answer (score 3):

Потому что название этого метода пишется не `__int__` (int - целое число), а `__init__` (инициализация):

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

На будущее: [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)